# Regular expression in R - remove everything after last symbol

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Using column `RelatedToText` below, I want to create 2 new columns `Coverage_Type` and `Name`.

If we can find content before and after last "-" sign, then I think I should be good.  But then, if you see the last case, there is a "-" sign between parts of a name i.e. between Mayur and Cook.

My questions are 2 fold : first, how should I extract content before and after the last "-" sign?, and second, how should I extract content correctly if name contains a dash within itself as quoted above?

```
RelatedToTxt                        Coverage_Type           Name
Collision - NAWADA REALTY, INC      Collision               NAWADA REALTY, INC
Collision - Don Cooks               Collision               Don Cooks
Pro Dam - Veh - Spl Lt - Raj Perk   Pro Dam - Veh - Spl Lt  Raj Perk
Rental Reimbursement - Mayur-Cook   Rental Reimbursement    Mayur-Cook
```

Example data:

```
RelatedToTxt <- c("Collision - NAWADA REALTY, INC", "Collision - Don Cooks",
    "Pro Dam - Veh - Spl Lt - Raj Perk", "Rental Reimbursement - Mayur-Cook")
```

Comment: For the first question, `.*` can be *very* greedy, which can help you. For your second question, take note of the fact that the "-" has no spaces around it. That should help differentiate. But you should show some code about what you've tried. SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: `strsplit(RelatedToTxt, "\\s*-\\s*(?=[^-]*$)", perl=T)` might be of help. Also, `gsub(".*-\\s*([^-]*)$", "\\1", RelatedToTxt)` and `gsub("(.*?)\\s*-\\s*[^-]*$", "\\1", RelatedToTxt)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew shouldn't `\\s*-\\s*` be `\\s+-\\s+` instead to prevent splitting on hyphenated names? I could be wrong, just curious.

Comment: @brittenb: I so wanna post a meme here saying "Nobody simply posts regex in comment and be right unless it's Wiktor".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Looks like [`-(?=[^-]+$)`](https://regex101.com/r/tD5nE6/1) works too.

Comment: @brittenb: I am about to fall asleep, right. `+`. Then, that approach won't work. noob, I am not always right.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew noob's comment is why I made my comment; your regex is always on point, so I wanted to know if I was missing something.

Comment: Perhaps, [`gsub(".*\\s+-\\s+(.*)", "\\1", RelatedToTxt)`, 
`gsub("(.*)\\s+-\\s+.*", "\\1", RelatedToTxt)` and `strsplit(RelatedToTxt, "\\s+-\\s+(?=[^-]*(?:(?<=\\S)-(?=\\S)[^-]*)*$)", perl=T)`](http://ideone.com/DbzeFt) will work.

Comment: Do any of the solutions offered so far help you?

Comment: Hi Jota. For good reason, I could not reply earlier. First, thank you for modifying my question by removing not-so-useful portions. Yes, these solutions are useful, but there are a couple of issues that I am facing. I would highlight them below.

Comment: @brittenb: Thank you for your input. You are right. I should show some code that I have tried. Generally, I do that, but this time I was not having much clue; hence, I did not mention.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thank you for sharing useful inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `strsplit` to split the text into two columns.  You can split on the final `" - "` using this regex:  `.+\\K\\s-\\s`.  The `.+\\K` uses a greedy pattern `.+` to match as much as it can and then drop what has been match, using `\\K`, before matching a space-hyphen-space pattern.  The greediness of `.+` allows it to skip over the hyphens in "Pro Dam - Veh - Spl Lt".

```
strsplit(RelatedToTxt, ".+\\K\\s-\\s", perl = TRUE)

#[[1]]
#[1] "Collision"          "NAWADA REALTY, INC"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "Collision" "Don Cooks"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "Pro Dam - Veh - Spl Lt" "Raj Perk"
#
#[[4]]
#[1] "Rental Reimbursement" "Mayur-Cook"
```

The output can be turned into two columns with

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(RelatedToTxt, ".+\\K\\s-\\s", perl = TRUE))
```

Comment: I think you can safely replace `(?!\\1+$)` with `.*$`. The previous greedy `.+` will match the last space-hyphen-space chunk in the string.

Comment: Yes, I was almost asleep when I wrote that. I meant that lookahead was redundant.

Comment: Your solution looks complete to me. Now I'm on my way to work. I was not able to post an answer at 1:00 AM.

Comment: @Jota: there are 2 issues that I am facing: 1. The vector RelatedToTxt that I cited actually contain millions of values. When I run above script, I find that number of rows in resulting matrix is less than length of this vector. Through some hit and trial, I have found an example in which above script does not return anything. Try this text <- c("(1) - ",""," ","(1) Injury - Split - Mayur","(1) Collision - ")
do.call(rbind,strsplit(text,".+\\K\\s-\\s", perl = TRUE)).

Comment: The output that I get is      
[,1]                              [,2]           
[1,] "(1)"                             "(1)"          
[2,] " "                               " "            
[3,] "(1) Bodily Injury - Split Limit" "Mayur"        
[4,] "(1) Collision"                   "(1) Collision" . But output that I want should have 5 rows, including one containing values of "" and "". This is just one example. I am not sure of other situations in which this above script would not return anything.

Comment: 2nd issue that I am facing is that I also have values such as "(1) Injury - Split Limit - Vinod Harris - Wise". As you would notice, when you run above script on this value, you would get "(1) Injury - Split Limit - Vinod Harris " and "Wise". However, what I want is "(1) Injury - Split Limit" and "Vinod Harris - Wise". The important thing to note is that the keyword "Injury - Split Limit " appears in many values. And there are many such keywords.

Comment: There is one more issue. Some of my values only contain first part i.e. only "(1) Injury - Split Limit". In such a case, above script would correctly split this value into 2 parts i.e. "(1) Injury" and "Split Limit", but I need splits of "(1) Injury - Split Limit" and "" (or "(1) Injury Split Limit"). Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @skumar you have basically changed the question.  The solution worked on the examples provided.  Are you expecting me to edit the solution I provided 4 days ago to accommodate the new example data?

Comment: @skumar The `do.call(rbind, strsplit(RelatedToTxt, ".+\\K\\s-\\s", perl = TRUE))` part can be modified to handle `do.call(rbind, strsplit(RelatedToTxt, ".+\\K\\s-\\s", perl = TRUE))`.  Just use `lapply` and extact the first and second elements of each list item.

Comment: @Jota: Thank you again for replying. I am not sure what is difference b/w first do.call and second do.call that you mentioned above. However, I think, I get the point of using lapply. I understand that I have changed my question slightly to incorporate more examples. If you can just mention some hint to handle such examples, it would be helpful to me.